# EF5 - Multiple recordsets from stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework

The best info I can find about using multiple recordsets is [Walkthrough: Multiple Result Sets from Stored Procedure (June CTP)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure.aspx).

However, with the current EF5 ([RC1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/05/15/ef5-release-candidate-available-on-nuget.aspx)), the suggested edits to the EDMX file - adding  elements, etc. do not work.  The XML fails validation, and the designer will not load it.

The source on [CodePlex](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) still includes the stored procedure called "Customer With Recent Orders", but it is not mapped or used anywhere!

I'm using VS2010 on .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my EDMX is set as Version 2.0, and this is only supported in Version 3.0.  Which means that it is only available with EF when running on .NET 4.5.

Guess I'll have to wait another week or two.

Comment: Is this clearly documented somewhere?  If so, I must have missed it.